# Como eliminar un valor (celda) dentro de una lista y dejarlo en blanco

Tags: python, formato

Que tal espero me puedan apoyar, estoy empezando con `python`, ya e realizado unos procesos para agilizar las actividades en mi trabajo, el detalle es el siguiente.

Tengo un archivo llamado `original.txt` el cual contiene números telefónicos 1234567890 (10 digitos) entonces en otro archivo llamado `tel.txt` tengo los teléfonos (solo una columna) que quiero quitar, el archivo `original.txt` no esta delimitado por nada solo por espacios así que en mi código le doy un rango de `[0:10]` y  de igual manera para `tel.txt [0:10]`.

El archivo `original.txt` puede tener 4 numeros en una sola fila o solo 1, eso quiere decir que tiene huecos,  lo que estoy haciendo es decirle que si los registro que tengo en `tel.txt` están en `original.txt` los elimine, el detalle es que me elimina toda la fila y yo solo quiero que quite el numero y lo deje en blanco, sin recorrer los registro que no altere el formato.

Ya se que existe el modulo de `pandas`, pero utilizo los equipo de mi trabajo y solo pude instalar `python`, no tengo privilegios para instalar módulos, por lo cual opte para usarlo en una lista.

Answer (score 2):

### El problema

Si entendí correctamente, el archivo `original.txt` podría tener por ejemplo algo así:

```
1111111111 2222222222 3333333333
4444444444 5555555555
6666666666
7777777777 8888888888 9999999999
```

y quieres eliminar algunos de los números que aparecen, pero dejando los restantes y respetando la estructura de líneas del fichero. Por ejemplo, si quisiéramos eliminar los número 2222222222, 6666666666 y 777777777, escribiríamos estos dos números en el fichero `tel.txt`, uno por fila, que contendría entonces:

```
2222222222
6666666666
7777777777
```

y entonces, el resultado tras el procesamiento debería ser:

```
1111111111 3333333333
4444444444 5555555555
8888888888 9999999999
```

en el que ya no aparecen dichos números, pero sí los restantes. Entiendo que si el número era el único de la línea, la línea debe desaparecer, en lugar de dejar una línea en blanco.

### Una solución

Una posible solución es leer cada línea del `original.txt`, separar su contenido por espacios para obtener una lista de números, y elminar de esa lista los que procedan. Si como resultado la lista queda vacía, no se escribe nada en el fichero resultado. De otro modo, se escribe los que hayan quedado en la lista, separados por espacios.

Para leer `tel.txt` también resulta útil tenerlos en una lista, lo que se logra leyendo el fichero entero "de una vez", en una sola cadena (si no es muy largo no hay problema en hacer esto), y dividir esa cadena con `.split()` que te la dividirá por retornos de carro, o espacios, o tabuladores. Esto te permite incluso que `tel.txt` tenga un formato más libre, en el que puede poner también varios números en una misma línea separados por espacios, o en varias líneas, sin que haya diferencia.

Una implementación de esta idea sería:

```
# Obtener lista de teléfonos a borrar
with open("tel.txt") as f:
    para_borrar = f.read().split()

# Abrir ficheros de entrada y de salida
with open("origen.txt") as f_input, open("resultado.txt", "w") as f_output:
    # Procesar fichero de entrada línea a línea
    for linea in f_input:
        # Obtener teléfonos en esa línea y quedarse sólo con los que proceda
        telefonos = linea.split()
        resultantes = [tel for tel in telefonos if tel not in para_borrar]
        if not resultantes:  # Si no queda ninguno, pasamos a la siguiente linea
            continue
        # En otro caso, volcamos el resultado
        f_output.write(" ".join(resultantes))
        f_output.write("\n")
```

## Actualización

Posteriormente el usuario aclara que quiere dejar "los huecos" que ocupaban los números eliminados. Esto es muy sencillo, basta alterar el filtro que eliminaba esos números, para que los sustituya por 10 espacios en blanco. Es decir, esta línea:

```
    resultantes = [tel for tel in telefonos if tel not in para_borrar]
```

se cambia a esta:

```
    resultantes = [tel if tel not in para_borrar else " "*10 for tel in telefonos]
```

Ahora el resultado de procesar los mismos ficheros antes mostrados sería este:

```
1111111111            3333333333
4444444444 5555555555

           8888888888 9999999999
```